# Setting ViewBag meta description in Layout file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying the following:

```
<meta name="description" content="@{ ViewBag.MetaDescription != null ? ViewBag.MetaDescription : "Welcome to the site!" }">
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement
```

Why isn't this ternary conditional working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
<meta name="description" content='@(ViewBag.MetaDescription ?? "Welcome to the site!")'>
```

Comment: Ah, the null-coalescing operator. I only learned about that recently and now I'm seeing it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`@{}` blocks do not innately return values.
You are essentially doing this:

```
function MyFunction()
{
    ViewBag.MetaDescription != null ? ViewBag.MetaDescription : "Welco"...
}
```

Try using `@Html.Raw()` or use a `@` statement instead.